# wostringstream, Ascii, Unicode, Win32 and integer concatenation to string

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode, ascii, stringstream

I am writing a library that uses Win32 APIs, and I would like to be able to compile it for both ASCII and Unicode (wide character is the `type`), and I am generating an internal class name (read: WinAPI "class") that I am appending an integer to a string to to create unique class names for various windows functions.

The definitions of the variables used:

```
LPCTSTR lpszClassName;    //  This is char* if ASCII, wchar_t* if Unicode.
#ifdef UNICODE
std::wostringstream Convert;
#else
std::ostringstream Convert;
#endif
```

The function in question:

```
void Base::MakeClassName () {
#ifdef _DEBUG_
    cerr << "Base::MakeClassName() called\n";
#endif
static int name_mod = 0;
name_mod++;
lpszClassName = TEXT("Win32WinNo");
Convert << lpszClassName << name_mod;
lpszClassName = Convert.str().c_str();

#ifdef _DEBUG_
    cerr << "Generated class name = " << lpszClassName << "\n";
#endif
}
```

In ASCII, I get `Generated class name = Win32WinNo1`

In Unicode, I get a hex value. Which suggests to me the wide character `wostringstream` is not doing what I want. Either way, CreateWindow doesn't seem to like it (program hangs, if I debug it, it crashes.)

I am not 100% familiar with stringstream, and going by the limited documentation, it returns a 'string' object, but I need a pointer to a C style string for LPCTSTR, so thus, the `Convert.str().c_str()`.  What I am getting is not working right, and If I try TEXT("Win32WinNo1") in my RegisterClass and CreateWindow calls, it works, but this returned string from above is junk.

What am I doing wrong? I am also concerned if it is not appending the integer to the string.  does wostringstream covert the integer to wchar_t?

Comment: You can save a lot of `#ifdef` mess by just defining `typedef std::basic_stringstream<TCHAR> tstringstream` etc. It just doesn't work for `std::cerr` since that's an object, not a type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ostringstream::str` returns a copy of the string object currently associated with the string stream buffer. `c_str` points to a buffer internal to that temporary string. `lpszClassName` is a dangling pointer as soon as this temporary string goes out of scope.

This is probably the reason why your program crashes/hangs.

Comment: `std::wostringstream Convert`  is defined in the same class as the function listed, so I am not sure how it can got out of scope, that's why it's defined outside the function.  (I just didn't list the whole class because it would be distracting an is not useful for this context.)

Comment: @Quade2002 but the temporary string returned by `Convert.str()` goes out of scope after the assignement to `lpszClassName`.

Comment: So, not the pointer its self, that I get and save, but the data it was pointing to, that goes out of scope?   Is it because of how I am chaining it together with c_str()?

Comment: Got it, basically, rather then leaving it up to a temporary string object, I explicitly created one and used it as a bridge between the stringstream and lpszClassName.  I am getting correct results now, if it is either ASCII or Unicode.  I created both a std::string and std::wstring version to keep all the types correct.  Yay!!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You output to `cerr`, which is still a narrow stream. It will likely display the pointer value of `lpszClassName` and not the wide string it points to.

Comment: ya, I was worried that cerr was doing something like this, that it is seeing the type and going with what was returned from c_str().  I thought this was a C style string, and since my object doesn't go out of scope, the pointer shouldn't go anywhere.  (Unless I am mis-understanding something here, and I might be, this is where I am a bit hazy.)  Question, is the String object (std::wstring) allocated by wostringstream also a wchar_t type?

Comment: Yes, a wide stringstream will return a `wstring` which `cerr` cannot handle. `wcerr` would though. You might ask yourself if you really *need* your code to compile for both `char` and `wchar_t`. Some people have stopped doing that, and instead use the `w`-version of everything.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to surround your string-literals with _T() so they will be `char`s or `wchar_t`s depending on your UNICODE settings.

For example `_T("Hello World")`.

Comment: don't forget to include <tchar.h>.

Comment: the `LPCTSTR` in `LPCTSTR lpszClassName`; is doing this for me.  depending on if UNICODE is set or not, it's defined the windows header files.

Comment: I believe the variable's type has no influence on the type of the string literal.